# Excel VBA need help checking multiple cell ranges with specific strings before outputting code

Tags: excel, vba, string, range

I am working on an Excel sheet where cells containing final shipment destinations need to be changed to the transit airport. As seen below my code is working for transit airport CUR. The only problem is that I want to change my code so the destinations are only changed if cell G5 contains for example route AMS-CUR. I am a noobie in coding and do not seem to figure it out

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim Mycell As Range

Set myRange = Range("D24:D56")
For Each Mycell In myRange
    If Mycell Like "BOG" Or _
       Mycell Like "LIM" Or _
       Mycell Like "VVI" Or _
       Mycell Like "PTY" Or _
       Mycell Like "SJO" Or _
       Mycell Like "POS" Or _
       Mycell Like "CCS" Or _
       Mycell Like "BGI" Then
       Mycell.Value = "CUR"

   End If
Next Mycell
```

[Pasted info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srGxj.png)
[When code is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQV2t.png)

Here 612-70011196 does not need to be changed to CUR but instead to PUJ.

I tried to set another myRange2 as range with different cell range and then used an if statement with multiple conditions but i got some compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is [INSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function). [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) is better for pattern matching much like Regular Expressions (AKA RegEx). Your statements would end up being something like this:

```
If Instr(myCell,"BOG", vbTextCompare) Or _
   Instr(myCell,"LIM", vbTextCompare) Or _
   ...
   Then MyCell.Value = "CUR"
```